# C# Draw Graph using EPPlus with sequential numbers\data in X-Axis similar to Y-Axis

Tags: c#, epplus

I need to draw a graph in Excel. I am using EPPLus to create the excel file.

I have data say

```
P1_Value : 22,43,56,87
P2_Value : 9,2,7,5
```

Now I need to plot the graph in Excel using EPPLus such that the graph displays sequential numbers in X-Axis  (**like how the Y-Axis values are shown across Y-Axis**) instead of having categories on X-Axis;

such that a graph is drawn taking coordinates points as `{(22,9),(43,2),(56,7),(87,5)}` on the X-Axis & Y-Axis.

But the code I've tried plots the X-Axis with values taking X Value Data as categories
and so X-axis has values as 
`Category 9,Category 2, Category 7 ... ,` instead of sequential values `2,4,6 ...`

My Current code:

```
ExcelLineChart lineChart = workSheet.Drawings.AddChart("lineChart", eChartType.Line) as ExcelLineChart;
        lineChart.Title.Text = GraphTitle;
         var rangeLabel = workSheet.Cells["D2:D2571"];
         var range1 = workSheet.Cells["C2:C2571"];

        lineChart.Series.Add(range1, rangeLabel);

        lineChart.Series[0].Header = workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value.ToString();
         lineChart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Right;
        lineChart.SetSize(600, 300);

        lineChart.SetPosition(5, 0, 1, 0);
```

**My Requirement**

I need to have X-Axis values as `1,2,3 ...` across X-Axis
like how

Y-Axis has values as `100,200 ...`

And the graph should accordingly plot for each coordinate 
Say for (22,9)  at the point 22,9 on the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Chart type to `ExcelScatterChart`  from `ExcelLineChart` solved my issue.